# How to block a favicon set by the server?

Tags: html, favicon

I don't want favicon for my website. Unfortunately my web hosting service imposes one. All my pages shows a favicon with the name of my hosting service.

*How can I get rid of the (commmercial) favicon?*

I could set a customised favicon but it is a personal website and I don't know what (very little) image could reflect me... And even if I found an idea, I don't have the time or skills to create a beautiful image.

I thought putting the html code without actually sending a image : (favicon.png does not exist)

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="img/favicon.png" />
```

But it's not working (it doesn't block the default favicon).

I could put a white image to override the commercial favicon but the rendering isn't beautiful (white empty favicon on gray browser...)

Comment: how about a transparent favicon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here! I made you a favicon :) Use it to your heart's content (if you like it).[image: It's a png]

Comment: thanks @Agony. I will use it. But do you have a png version ?

Comment: Sadly that was a png, but the way SO puts images on there it is posted as a jpeg. You should be able to just right click, save as, then click the drop down to "All Files" and change the extension to .png.

Comment: Yes it does. I believe it's because SO uploads images via imgur and converts all images to .jpg before uploading. I just edited my answer and uploaded it again, but again it's a .jpg :\